# td's in table creating with jquery without html

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bbogdanov/6dw2u8uz/12/) is my jsfiddle work. I have some issues with generating table without any html. I have one json object that i need to itterate and to put keys and values in table like:

```
<tr> <td> key </td> <td> key </td> ... </tr>
<tr> <td> val </td> <td> val </td> ... </tr>
```

I tried first to generate the table like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bbogdanov/ykqd3buu/7/) one, but next i wanted to use jquery version of creating `td`'s and `tr`'s, but the all keys and values were appended in only one `td` and actually this is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through keys the first time to set the `head` of table, after that make the rows inside `each` and append every one to the table to make the `body` of your table, check example code bellow :

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url : '/echo/json/',
    data : { json: JSON.stringify( jsonData ) },
    success : function(data){
        var jsn = $(data.markers);

        //First time append table head
        if(!header)
        { 
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');

            for(key in jsn[0])
            {
                row.append('<th>'+key+'</th>');
            }

            table.append(row);

            header = true;
        }

        for ( var i = 0; i < jsn.length ; i++){
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');

            $.each(jsn[i], function(key,val)
            {
                row.append('<td>'+val+'</td>');
            });

            table.append(row);
        }

    }        
});
```

Take a look at **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/64/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, it helps a lot. Actually this is what i wanted to do. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the scope of the `col` and `row` variables. You must reassign them in the loop, or redeclare.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6dw2u8uz/14/) is the updated jsfiddle. By the way there is no need to use `for` loop. In jQuery it is enough to use the `$.each` function on the object.

From here you can see how to create table structure and replace the `key` and `val` with the actual data you need.

Comment: Thank you for the advise with `$.each()`. I used `for` cause i had some issues with `$.each()` and i got confused what $.each will return me in some moments, so i made it more readable for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new row object in each `for` iteration:

```
for (var mrksIndex = 0, mrksLength = jsn.length; mrksIndex <= mrksLength; ++mrksIndex) {
    row = $("<tr/>");
    $.each(jsn[mrksIndex], function (key, val) {
        col = $("<td/>");
        col.append(key);
        row.append(col);
        table.append(row);
    });
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/6dw2u8uz/15/